# How do I loop an if, elif else statement?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, input

I am writing code for a project and I would like some help.

When the user enters something other than male or female, it prints the message "Error! Please enter a valid gender!", but it doesn't rerun the input statement, so it doesn't let them pick a gender. I would like to know how to have the input line rerun again after the user receives the error message. Please let me know how I can do this using Python 3.0!

This is my code:

```
Gender = input("Your Gender (Male / Female):")
gender = Gender.lower()
if gender == "male":
  heorshe = "he"
  hisher = "his"
  himher = "him"
  himselfherself = "himself"
  HeShe = "He"
elif gender == "female":
  heorshe = "she"
  hisher = "her"
  himher = "her"
  himselfherself = "herself"
  HeShe = "He"
else:
  print("Error Please enter a valid gender!")
  print('\n')
  gender = False
```

I will appreciate any help given to me!

Comment: use a while loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Yes, you can wrap your code in an infinite loop like `while True` and `break` out of it once you receive a correct input.

Comment: @yeputons How would I wrap it in an infinite loop like that? For instance, where would I put the while True and break lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate in a while-loop, then break out of it when you find what you're looking for!

```
while(True):
  gender = input("Your Gender (Male / Female):").lower()
  if gender == "male":
    heorshe = "he"
    hisher = "his"
    himher = "him"
    himselfherself = "himself"
    HeShe = "He"
    break
  elif gender == "female":
    heorshe = "she"
    hisher = "her"
    himher = "her"
    himselfherself = "herself"
    HeShe = "He"
    break
  else:
    print("Error Please enter a valid gender!")
    print('\n')
```